# Android LinearLayout multiple columns while preserving addView(view, position) functionality

Tags: android, android-layout

How do you enable 2 or more columns on a `LinearLayout` while still preserving the capability to use `addView(view, position)` to add views at a given position.

Nested layouts aren't an option because in that case, each inner layout will have it's own indexes. I want to be able to use the `addView` method on the main layout such that the view goes to the appropriate column.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use tablelayout instead of linearlayout

Answer (score 0):

I'd use 2 separate LinearLayouts, possibly within an outer LinearLayout, and have one LinearLayout be the left column, and the other be the right column. These 2 new LinearLayouts will both have equal `android:layout_weight` so that they have equal widths in the outer layout. You can then choose whether to add the new view to the left column or the right column by its ID.